# Ng-repeat generate error when set type-color dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some problem when I use the plugin alert inside a ng-repeat that is inside other ng-repeat.

I have a screen where I have to select a category and then I need to select some products. This selected products appear within the alert plugin, and I have four buttons to select the level of importance of the selected product.

Each button, set a diferent style, success, info, warning and danger in the alert container.

The problem is: If I select two categories, and sames products for these two categories, when I change the style of one product, the other same product set the style too.

My code is:

```
<div style='position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;' ng-repeat="cid in listaCidSelected[$index]">
    <alert type="{{cid.type}}" close="removerCid(tuss, cid, $index)">
        {{cid.CIDSC_DS_DESCRICAO}}
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary" ng-click="definirTipoCid('success', cid, $index)"><label>Sem Importância</label></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-info" ng-click="definirTipoCid('info', cid, $index)"><label>Média</label></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-warning" ng-click="definirTipoCid('warning', cid, $index)"><label>Grave</label></button>&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-danger" ng-click="definirTipoCid('danger', cid, $index)"><label>Gravíssima</label></button>&nbsp;
    </alert>
</div>
```

If I have two categories or more selected and use same products for each category, the alerts of this product repeat the same style: (`type="{{cid.type}}"`)

Complementing with the controller methods:

```
$scope.checkAssociarCidHandler = function(tuss, index, event){
      $scope.listaCheckCid[index] = !$scope.listaCheckCid[index];
      event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.listaCheckCid[index] ? "Finalizar Associação" : "Associar Motivo(s)";
      // Seleciona os checks com as CIDs ja selecionadas
      if ($scope.listaCheckCid[index]){
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listaTussSelected.length; i++) {
              if ($scope.listaTussSelected[i].TUSSPR_CD_CODIGO == tuss.TUSSPR_CD_CODIGO){
                  for (var j = 0; j < $scope.listaCidSelected[i].length; j++) {
                      document.querySelector("#ckItemCheckT" + tuss.TUSSPR_CD_CODIGO + 'C' + $scope.listaCidSelected[i][j].CIDSC_CD_CODIGO).checked = true;   
                  }
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }


  $scope.checkCidHandler = function(cid, tuss, event){
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listaTussSelected.length; i++) {
          if ($scope.listaTussSelected[i].TUSSPR_CD_CODIGO == tuss.TUSSPR_CD_CODIGO){
              // Associa uma CID
              if (event.currentTarget.checked){
                  cid.type = "info";
                  $scope.listaCidSelected[i].push(cid);
              }else{
                  // Desassocia uma CID
                  for (var j = 0; j < $scope.listaCidSelected[i].length; j++) {
                      if ($scope.listaCidSelected[i][j].CIDSC_CD_CODIGO == cid.CIDSC_CD_CODIGO){
                          $scope.listaCidSelected[i].splice(j, 1);
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
              break;
          }
      }
  }

  // Define a cor da CID
  $scope.definirTipoCid = function(tipo, cid, index){
      cid.type = tipo;
  }
```

Have Someone any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: would you please share the code of your controller?

Comment: I shared the methods involved! Thank you for your reply Shim br!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the product is the same in 2 categories then will change boths (since is the same objects), what you can do is clone your products for each category before.

```
category.products = angular.copy(original_products)
```

Something like this. Here the copy documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Another tip, never chage DOM in your controller, use directives for that.

Comment: Hi Scoup, becouse the product selection is dynamic. I never know when the user will select the same product. When the user select another category,  this new category can or not have some products that the preview category have.

Imagine that you have to make two shop list, and in both list you need one "Mouse Pad".

Thank you for your help, and your tip!

Comment: So, you can aways clone the products for categories, when you "set" the products of a category use the "copy", you will use more memory, but I don't think will be a problem if not too much products. I can't think another way.

Comment: Scoup, I understand why it'is necessary make a copy of the object. 
It's work my friend.  

I'm just copy the object and works fine.

    var novaCid = angular.copy(cid);     $scope.listaCidSelected[i].push(novaCid);

Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This is the major problem with Angularjs , It is dur to cloning, actually it provides the refrence to both of them not the data , I solved the problem by push the elements into a seperate array or container, then is works fine for me. 
Thanks

Comment: Dinesh,

Yes, it's necessary copy the object.

Thank you